# How to find average and percentage of total marks using function. C++

Tags: c++, oop

Write a function that receives marks received by a student in 3 subjects and returns the
average and percentage of these marks. Call this function from main( ) and print the
results in main( ).

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int mark()
{
    int mark[3];
    int sum;
    float *average, *percentage;
    cout << "Enter the marks of urdu, english and islamiat out of 100" << endl;
    cin >> mark[1] >> mark [2] >> mark [3];
    sum = mark[1] + mark[2] + mark[3];
    *average = sum/3;
    *percentage =(sum/300)*100;
}


int main()
{
    int x, y;
    mark();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: #include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int mark()
{
int mark[3];
int sum;
float *average, *percentage;
cout << "Enter the marks of urdu, english and islamiat out of 100" << endl;
cin >> mark[1] >> mark [2] >> mark [3];
sum = mark[1] + mark[2] + mark[3];
*average = sum/3;
*percentage =(sum/300)*100;
}


int main()
{
int x, y;
mark();
return 0;
}

Comment: Please edit the question rather than posting code as a comment.

Comment: Sidenote: Your mark function doesn't return anything so the type should be void.

Answer (score 0):

Pass in the pointers to average and percentage as arguments to your function. That way you will have access to them from main.

By the way typically you would read the input in main(or a second function) and pass the values as arguments to your function. It is better design to make your code more testable and reusable.

Answer (score 0):

This program works!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void mark(float *average)
{
int markg[3], sum;
string mg[] = { "first", "second", "third" };
cout << "Enter the marks of urdu, english and islamiat out of 100" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
       cout << "Enter " << mg[i] << " mark:";
       cin >> markg[i];
    }
sum = markg[0] + markg[1] + markg[2];
*average = sum / 3;
}

int main()
{
float average;
mark(&average);
cout << "Average = " << average << endl;
return 0;
}
```

I have used a pointer. 
I have used markg[] to distinguish it form the function mark().
I have the user enter each mark one at a time. If you use cin >> markg[1] ...
It might cause errors.
You could use getline to input a string then parse what you need from it.
I chosed the simplier method.
As you defined average and percent they are the same. You may want to ask you professor for clarification on this point.
I hope that you find this advise helpful.